# Inner Product - Gramm-Schmidt Process

Tags: inner-products

I am trying to check over some work that was done in class by my professor and I am stuck on one part where my answer does not match his answer:

We were given the space $L^2(-1,1)$ where $M=$span$\{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4,\dots\}$ where $g_0=1, g_1=x,$ etc.

For the Gramm-Schmidt Process to replace the vectors with mutually orthogonal vectors:
$$f_0=g_0$$
$$f_1=g_1-\hat{g}_1=g_1-\bigg(\displaystyle\frac{\langle g_1,f_0\rangle}{\langle f_0,f_0\rangle} \cdot f_0\bigg)$$

Note: $\langle g_1,f_0\rangle = \displaystyle\int_{-1}^{1} (g_1 \cdot f_0)\, dx,$ etc.

So,

$$f_0=g_0=1$$
$$f_1=g_1-\hat{g}_1 = x$$

For $f_2$:
$$f_2=g_2-\hat{g}_2 = g_2 -\bigg(\displaystyle\frac{\langle g_2,f_1\rangle}{\langle f_1,f_1\rangle} \cdot f_1 + \frac{\langle g_2, f_0\rangle}{\langle f_0,f_0\rangle}\cdot f_0\bigg)$$
$$= x^2 - (0\cdot x + \displaystyle\frac{\frac{2}{3}}{0} \cdot 1)$$

The given solution for $f_2$ that was given to me was $x^2-\frac{1}{3}$.

Is there an error in my calculations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

$$\frac{\langle g_2, f_0\rangle}{\langle f_0,f_0\rangle}=\frac{\frac23}{2}=\frac13$$

Comment: isn't it from $-1$ to $1$?

Comment: yes sorry i had an error in my problem above. the space is $L^2(-1,1)$

Comment: i see my mistake now..thanks !

Comment: @rover2 You are welcome! indeed I was looking to the integral which defines the inner product!

Answer (score 2):

Since you're working in the space $L^2(0,1)$, your inner product should be to take the integral from $0$ to $1$, not from $-1$ to $1$. Once you do that, I think your method should produce $x^2 - \frac13$.

***Edit:*** Now that it's been clarified that the space is $L^2(-1,1)$, please refer to gimusi's answer.

Comment: is there a reason why the integral changes?

Comment: @rover2 The integral is just over whatever space you're working with -- if it's $(0,1)$, then it's over $(0,1)$, and if it's $(-1,1)$, then it's over $(-1,1)$.

Comment: @rover2 Think about this: if you had a function $f$ which was square-integrable over $(0,1)$ but not $(-1,1)$, and you tried to take $\langle f,f \rangle$ by integrating over $(-1,1)$, you wouldn't get an answer. That's why integrating over $(-1,1)$ wouldn't be a good inner product for $L^2(0,1)$.

Comment: SORRY! I HAD AN ERROR IN MY PROBLEM..the space is $L^2(-1,1)$

Comment: @rover2 In that case, gimusi is correct.